# Delete first node in Binary Search Tree Java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am learning about Binary Search Tree and working on a project. When I tried to delete the first node I inserted, it doesn't delete and still show that node when I call showAll method. Is that how Binary Search Tree works or did I do something incorrectly?

Thanks,

Here is the code for BinarySearchTree class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree_Pham {
    TreeNode root;

    public BinarySearchTree_Pham() {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean insert(Student_Pham newStudent) {
        TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
        if(n == null)
            return false;
        else {
            n.node = newStudent.deepCopy();
            n.lc = null;
            n.rc = null;
            if(root == null) {
                root = n;
            }
            else {
                findNode(newStudent.getId(), p, c);
                if(newStudent.getId().compareTo(p.get().node.getId()) < 0)
                    p.get().lc = n;
                else
                    p.get().rc = n;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } //end insert

    public Student_Pham fetch(String id) {
        boolean found;
        TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        found = findNode(id, p, c);
        if (found == true)
            return c.get().node.deepCopy();
        else
            return null;
    } //end fetch

    public boolean delete(String id) {
        boolean found;
        TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNode largest;
        TreeNode nextLargest;
        found = findNode(id, p, c);
        if(found == false)
            return false;
        else {
            if(c.get().lc == null && c.get().rc == null) {
                if (p.get().lc == c.get())
                    p.get().lc = null;
                else
                    p.get().rc = null;
            } //end case 1
            else if (c.get().lc == null || c.get().rc == null) {
                if (p.get().lc == c.get()) {
                    if (c.get().lc != null)
                        p.get().lc = c.get().lc;
                    else
                        p.get().lc = c.get().rc;
                }
                else {
                    if (c.get().lc != null)
                        p.get().rc = c.get().lc;
                    else
                        p.get().rc = c.get().rc;
                }
            } // end case 2
            else {
                nextLargest = c.get().lc;
                largest = nextLargest.rc;
                if (largest != null) {
                    while (largest.rc != null) {
                        nextLargest = largest;
                        largest = largest.rc;
                    }
                    c.get().node = largest.node;
                    nextLargest.rc = largest.lc;
                }
                else {
                    nextLargest.rc = c.get().rc;
                    if (p.get().lc == c.get())
                        p.get().lc =nextLargest;
                    else
                        p.get().rc = nextLargest;
                }
            } // end case 3
            return true;
        }
    } // end of delete

    public boolean update(String id, Student_Pham newStudent) {
        if(delete(id) == false)
            return false;
        else if (insert(newStudent) == false)
            return false;
        return true;
    } // end update

    public void showAll() {
        if (root == null)
            System.out.println("Structure is empty.");
        else
            LNRoutputTraversal(root);
    } //end showAll

    private void LNRoutputTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        if (root.lc != null)
            LNRoutputTraversal(root.lc);
        System.out.println(root.node);
        if (root.rc != null)
            LNRoutputTraversal(root.rc);
    }

    public class TreeNode {
        private Student_Pham node;
        private TreeNode lc;
        private TreeNode rc;
        public TreeNode() {}
    }

    private boolean findNode(String targetKey, TreeNodeWrapper parent, TreeNodeWrapper child) {
        parent.set(root);
        child.set(root);
        if (root == null)
            return true;
        while (child.get() != null) {
            if(child.get().node.getId().compareTo(targetKey) == 0)
                return true;
            else {
                parent.set(child.get());
                if(targetKey.compareTo(child.get().node.getId()) < 0)
                    child.set(child.get().lc);
                else
                    child.set(child.get().rc);
            }
        } //end while
        return false;
    }

    public class TreeNodeWrapper {
        TreeNode treeRef = null;
        public TreeNodeWrapper() {}
        public TreeNode get() {return treeRef;}
        public void set(TreeNode t) {treeRef = t;}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, and you're missing your Student_Pham class. Can you simplify the problem? I didn't want to spend 15 minutes just to get something that builds.

Comment: Instead of providing the code it would be helpful if you could provide simple class diagrams which represent your tree structure with necessary variables and methods and then show us your implementation of the code to remove the first node. I think this would make your question more accessible. (I recommend draw.io (if it is allowed here) to create those UML diagrams fast and simple)

Comment: Basically, this code is to manage a list of Student_Pham objects which are students’ information using Binary Search Tree structure. When I call the delete method, it doesn’t delete the first student I insert.

Comment: I think the most helpful thing you can do is peppering the code with prints all over to see what exactly is going on, how the tree looks like, how the nodes look like, see if certain lines of code you are assuming are executed are actually executed. This will probably help you understand what's going on and eliminate some of your assumptions.